# how to change the theme of application dynamically in app.xaml.cs file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have two resource dictionaries

> 1. DarkTheme.xaml
> 2. LightTheme.xaml

I load the `LightTheme` by default when the application starts in app.xaml file using the following code

```
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/LightTheme.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>

</Application.Resources>
```

I want to give an option to user that he can change the theme of application as he likes problem is that how can i load the `DarkTheme.xaml` file when user chooses that theme and load `LightTheme.xaml` file when it is chosen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries[0] = 
    new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("Themes/LightTheme.xaml", UriKind.Relative) };
```